# vim, change "paragraph separator" definition

Tags: vim

I'm writing python code, and I'm facing to an annoying problem with the `{` and `}` moving keys : the vim definition for paragraphs is "blocks separated by an empty line".
However, when I code in python a class, I like to keep the indentation between methods, so is there an easy way to do paragraphs move to move like this :

```
class A:
  def f(): #cursor here, when I type {, go between f and g
    return 1

  #the previous line is indented
  def g():
    return 2
```

Of course, it's always possible to remap `}` as a function doing

```
let a = @/
normal /\S\n\s*$/
normal j
let @/ = a
```

and `{` to a similar
but is there an easier way ?

Answer (score 3):

The default python ftplugin already redefines `[m` and `]m` to jump to previous and next `^\s*\(def\|class\)`.

Comment: yep... I didn't know about `[m`, ty :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution posted by @romainl is fine, but you might also want to look at Kana's [textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user).  It's a framework for defining [text objects](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#text-objects).  Among other things, there is a [plugin](https://github.com/bps/vim-textobj-python) that uses this to define text objects for Python, which in turn have keys for moving across functions and classes.  People have written many other [similar plugins](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/wiki).